# Local File from repository not saved after edit (groovy / jenkins)

Tags: json, jenkins, groovy

In my Jenkins Job i checked out a repository. In that repo, there is a file which i want to edit during the job. But it seems that the file is not saved. I have a Method like this:

```
def updateFile(id, key){
    def inputFile = readFile("${workspace}/config/cnf.json")
    def inputJSON = new JsonSlurper().parseText(inputFile)

    inputJSON."${key}"[0].pref = "${id}"
    def result = JsonOutput.toJson(inputJSON)
    //here it is changed.
    println "result:\n${result}"
    inputFile << "${JsonOutput.prettyPrint(result)}"
    //and now it is again the old one.
    println "Hier: \n ${inputFile}"
}
```

Problem is, that i can't use "new File" and ".write" or ".append" because Jenkins cant find the File that way.

```
def inputFile = new File("${workspace}/config/cnf.json") --> no File found
```

Is there any good way to save the existing File?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `readFile("${workspace}/config/cnf.json")` works fine

then to write file use [writeFile](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#writefile-write-file-to-workspace) like this:

```
writeFile file:"${workspace}/config/cnf.json", text:result
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I tested it. But i get the error: java.io.NotSerializableException: groovy.json.internal.LazyMap :-(

Comment: use `JsonSlurperClassic` instead of  `JsonSlurper`. you can use in jenkins pipeline only serializable objects. and JsonSlurperClassic returns normal `java.util.HashMap` instead of `LazyMap`.